# Alternative to eval for dynamically evaluating mixed content strings (html + php) within php script

Tags: php, html, string, dynamic, eval

Let's just get right into it.

*index.php*

```
<?php
    ...
    $url = "www.google.com";
    $val = "Is PHP better than Perl?";
    $file = file_get_contents("mixedcontent.txt");
    print eval("?>" . $file . "<?");
    ...
?>
```

*mixedcontent.txt*

```
<html>
...
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
        <input id="q" type="text" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"/>
    </form>
...
</html>
```

The two files are just as stubs and are required to be separate, due to the limitations of the commercial software on which it is dependent.

Now, I realize that eval is viewed by many as a last resort and most suggest a redesign, since eval can be a security risk. Is there an alternative to using eval for dynamically evaluating mixed content (i.e. html + php)?  Could I somehow utilize create_function or call_user_func?

Thank you.

**Update**

Based on the recommendations in the comments and answers sections to use include for this particular type of example, I have modified the code:

*index.php*

*index.php*

```
<?php
    ...
    $url = "www.google.com";
    $val = "Is PHP better than Perl?";
    include("mixedcontent.txt");
    ...
?>
```

That looks like it works well.  Thank you very  much to all.

Comment: In your code example, `include` seems enough.

Comment: If the text file is local, `include` should be fine. If it's external I'm not sure `include` will work due to security limitations.

Comment: As I stated below to Dharmesh, I don't believe I understand how include would be applicable here.  I've used include to import php files.  Here, I'm printing out mixed content (html + php) from another file. I would appreciate an example of the above or something similar using include, for I don't understand how I can replace eval and use include to print mixed content.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jared, `include` is the way to go, but if you don't want to use it or if it is not working for you. then you can try following, which I think is better alternative

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#108091

Comment: Thank you very much.  Everyone is suggesting include, but I am still bewildered how it work.  Can you please show an example of using include with either the sample above or something similar?  I've always used include for importing other php files.  I don't see how I can use include to print out mixed content (html + php) from one file from within a php file.  Thank you for your help.